# ReactJs + Webapi How do you do external authentication?

Tags: c#, authentication, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, oauth

I am building a reactjs website that will communicate with asp.net web api 2 to save and retreive data.

but I am not sure how to do this.

I know to accomplish this on a high level it would be something like

1. User comes to my site and hits signup/log
2. Chooses which provider then want to use(google, facebook and etc). I am only want to support external providers(ie I don't want to have to deal with usernames/pwds)
3. User it sent to authenticated part of site
4. User clicks "add course" that data send via ajax to webapi with some sort of token to prove they have access to these methods.

I am not sure how to implement this problems I see is

1. Reactjs I guess is handling the authentication part? then once they been authenticated it would have to be saved in my db via webapi so it knows about this new user?
2. Reactjs would have to block users from going to secure pages till they are authenticated
3. Web api would have to generate a token for the user for that session so they can access the web api(I want to stop people from consuming my api).

Is there some simple example out there how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Reactjs I guess is handling the authentication part? then once they been authenticated it would have to be saved in my db via webapi so it knows about this new user

Better use some third party auth library here like [PassportJS](http://passportjs.org/) that does the auth for you using strategies like [Passport-Facebook](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook). This will give you an Oauth access token from Facebook upon authentication. You can now save this token in your cookies (or localStorage), take a look at the [security considerations](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/80767).

Should you store it in a DB? [Here are some arguments about it](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/72475/should-we-store-accesstoken-in-our-database-for-oauth2).

> 2. Reactjs would have to block users from going to secure pages till they are authenticated

This can be done by checking if they have a valid token.

> 3. Web api would have to generate a token for the user for that session so they can access the web api(I want to stop people from consuming my api).

This can be easily achieved by using [JSON Web Tokens](https://jwt.io/). Note that you will have to store the JWT in your client side locally, along side your FB-Google oauth tokens (or you can relegate that to a single API by storing them in DB?. Its a design choice, I would prefer to store them separately and save a lot of hassle).

Comment: Cool, I was unsure if I could use passport as I thought I needed some node thing. I guessing I have to save the tokens in my database. How else would I know if the user is really who they say they are when they make a request to grab say all their courses? Or am I missing something? Do you hae any quick example. I not clear what you mean about "relegate that to a single api." I rather do the simpler way and keep it separate in 2 fields in the db if need be.